# Flash plugin in Chromium available in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, flash, chromium

Now that I've installed 16.04, I'm not able to view news that require Flash for streaming on Chromium. I've installed Flash, and the plugin works on Firefox. Is there a different plugin I should try for Chromium?

Answer (score -1):

Add the Canonical Partners software source, and install adobe-flashplugin.See the webpage at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.